# Why does it keep saying user is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm writing a function that calls a prop that calls objects in an array and it keeps throwing this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...robots.map...')

I assume it's talking about user, but I don't know. Any help would be greatly appreciated here's my code

The error is being thrown on this file CardList.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Card from './Card';

    const CardList = ({ robots }) =>{
    //the line under this is the one throwing the error
      const cardComponent = robots.map((user, i)=>{ 
        return <Card id={robots[i].id} name={robots[i].name} email=  {robots[i].email} /> 
      });
      return(
        <div>
          {cardComponent}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default CardList;
```

here is the robots.js file, I just put a couple of the objects in the array so you get the idea.

```
    export const robots = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Leanne Graham',
        username: 'Bret',
        email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Ervin Howell',
        username: 'Antonette',
        email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Clementine Bauch',
        username: 'Samantha',
        email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
      }
    ];
```

here is the index.js file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import CardList from './CardList';
    import { robots } from './robots';
    import 'tachyons';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

    ReactDOM.render(<CardList robots={'robots'}/>, document.getElementById('root'));

    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` means that you are trying to execute something as a function but it's actually `undefined`. If it's the `robots.map()` line that throws this error, then `robots.map` is `undefined` for some reason.

Comment: `CardList robots={'robots'}` I'm not good with JSX but does this pass an object with the `robots` object in it? Because it seems to me that it will create a `{robots: "robots"}` object, so in the `CardList` after destructuring the parameter via `({ robots }) =>{` you'd get the *string* `"robots"` as the content of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo here : 
`ReactDOM.render(<CardList robots={'robots'}/>, document.getElementById('root'));`

It should be: 
 `ReactDOM.render(<CardList robots={robots}/>,document.getElementById('root'));`
 with `robots` being  the name of the variable you are importing and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string (`'robots'`) instead of an array (`robots`) imported from `'./robots'`.
So, `map` function exists on Array's prototype but not on String's prototype which is why it is throwing the error.

To fix this,

`<CardList robots={'robots'}/>`

should be replaced with

`<CardList robots={robots}/>`